# How do I install OIM 11gPS2 using a separate VM server to host the DB

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle12c, identity-management

I am attempting to install OIM 11gPS2 using the deployment wizard.

There are very good descriptions of the process by idmrockstar at:

http://idmrockstar.com/blog/2014/07/oracle-identity-management-11gr2-deployment-wizard-with-amazon-ec2-setup-walkthrough/

and

idm.guru at:

http://idm.guru/access-governance/deploying-the-iam-suite-with-the-deployment-wizard/

Both however are hosting the Oracle DB on the same server.  I want to call a DB hosted on a separate server.

How is this achieved?

Config:

OIM 11gPS2 running on Linux 6.5 with 10Gb RAM and 200 GB HDD
Oracle db 12c running on Linux 6.5 with 3Gb RAM and 30Gb HDD.

PS.  This is for evaluation only and not a production deployment, hence the small amount of resources.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install OIM on Oracle Virtual Box (Linux 5) running the database on the same machine using the [oracle install documents](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/install.1112/e27301/oim.htm#INOAM1216). I would assume that to use a database on a separate virtual machine you would just change the hostname under section 5.7.4 step 4 of the document.

I did install OAM on a separate Virtual machine and point the instillation back to the OIM machine to use it's database, so it is possible.